# Align label widget to left of EventBox

Tags: gtk

I have been trying to align an entire label along with text to the left of an `GtkEventBox` where I placed it. However, I cannot do so. I tried to align the text on the label, because I do not know of any functions that would align the label itself to the left of my event box. The event box is placed in the table in this code:

```
label1 = gtk_label_new(res);
gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(label1), GTK_JUSTIFY_LEFT);
gtk_label_set_line_wrap (GTK_LABEL (label1), TRUE);
gtk_label_set_single_line_mode(GTK_LABEL(label1),TRUE);

//align = gtk_alignment_new(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
//gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(align), label1);
//gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), align, 0, 10, 2, 3, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, 20, 10);

embedLabel= gtk_event_box_new();
gtk_container_add( GTK_CONTAINER(embedLabel), label1 );
gtk_container_set_resize_mode(GTK_CONTAINER(embedLabel), FALSE);
gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), embedLabel, 0, 10, 2, 3, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, 20, 20);
```

Comment: Use **gtk_alignment_set ()** with the proper values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to [set the alignment](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkMisc.html#gtk-misc-set-alignment) within the available space?

```
gtk_misc_set_alignment(GTK_MISC(label1), 0, .5);
```